# Multiply count result by 1/2

Tags: sql

I need to multiply the count from cells in a qa table x .5. 
Essentially,

```
select count (distinct (individual)) 
from qatable 
where cellcode in ('cell 1', 'cell 2', 'cell 3', 'cell 4', 'cell 5') * .5
```

```
Cell 1 is 150,
Cell 2 is 175,
Cell 3 is 200,
Cell 4 is 225,
Cell 5 is 250,

Cells 1-5 = 1000
```

I would need to show that the result is 500 (1/2 of cells 1-5)

Any ideas?

Comment: Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the question tags and include the structure of your table, and tell us how to determine the "prior" row of your table given the "current" row. Also, what does "the count of an email" mean. Do you mean "the length of the text of the email", or something else? And where can the text of the email be found? Thanks.

Comment: You can't multiply an `IN(...)` clause, but you can multiply the result of `COUNT()`:

   `select count (distinct (individual)) * 0.5 from qatable where ...`

Comment: Can you add some sample data and expected result? A few rows of data will help a lot.

Comment: This data is in a format that has less than nothing to do with SQL. As this is a SQL question, the least you can do is express it as something we can run SQL queries against. You're not only asking us to solve the problem, but to structure the data so the problem can be solved, and more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need to move your math up into the body of your query.

```
SELECT SUM(<WhateverColumnThoseNumbersAreIn>) * .5
FROM qatable
WHERE cellcode IN (
         'cell 1'
        ,'cell 2'
        ,'cell 3'
        ,'cell 4'
        ,'cell 5'
        );
```

But I feel as though I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate if you could mark this as your accepted answer by clicking on the grey check mark to the left. Only you can see it, but once you click it, it will turn green and be visible to everybody. That will give each of us some reputation points, and lets other users know that this question has an answer. Thanks!